# Rails generating/caching rarely changing datasets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

In a website I am working on I have cases with an expensive controller endpoint (5+ seconds between request received and having the response ready) that outputs data sourced from database tables that nearly never change.

The only time I expect the response to change is once every few months when I get new source data, or when redeploying the site with related code changes.

As such I am thinking of just creating the resulting JSON, etc. files to then serve statically. But is there a Rails way to do this, rather than just some custom CLI script that creates a bunch of files I then commit? Ideally still being able to use ActiveRecord etc. maybe as some sort of build/deploy time action?

Comment: You could use Rails' built-in caching mechanism: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Comment: as in like "render text: Rails.cache.fetch("static.json") do ...to_json() end"? Is that actually considered good practice? What about efficiently handling client caching as well (ETag / If-Modified, etc.)?

Comment: [This article on Rails caching](http://sorentwo.com/2015/10/19/layering-api-defenses-with-caching.html) might prove useful; it covers not just the basic case of JSON caching but also more advanced cases that often come up as your application evolves.